# Array not showing up in View after being generated from function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this simple function that groups products into their respective categories. You can also see I'm calling the function within a timeout.

Problem is, even though the console.log() works like it should, I can't see anything in my view.

```
function sortByCategories(){
        var temp = [];
        angular.forEach(admin.categories, function(category, value){
            angular.forEach(admin.products, function(product, value){
                angular.forEach(product.categories, function(prodCat, value){
                    if(prodCat.text == category.text)
                    {
                        if(!temp[category.text])
                        {
                            temp[category.text] = [];
                        }

                        temp[category.text].push(product);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
        admin.sortedProducts = temp;
    }

    $timeout(function(){
        sortByCategories();
        console.log(admin.sortedProducts); // This shows me what I expect.
    }, 3500);
```

My html in my view is simply just `<pre>{{admin.sortedProducts | json}}</pre>`

All I see in my view is `[]`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I moved this function into a service and placed it as a resolve in my route. I am still facing the same issue. Here is what I have.

```
.factory('Products', function($rootScope, $timeout, $q, fbUrl, $firebaseArray){
    return {
        sortByCategories: function() {
            var temp = [];
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl);
            ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
                var categories = snapshot.child('categories').val();
                var products = snapshot.child('products').val();

                angular.forEach(categories, function(category, value) {
                    angular.forEach(products, function(product, value){
                        angular.forEach(product.categories, function(prodCat, value){
                            if(prodCat.text == category.url)
                            {
                                if(!temp[category.url])
                                {
                                    temp[category.url] = [];
                                }

                                temp[category.url].push(product);
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
                deferred.resolve(temp);
            })
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

And then in my route I have this in a resolve:

```
...
resolve: {
   categorySortedProducts : function(Products){
       return Products.sortByCategories();
   }
}
...
```

Then that's loaded in my controller

```
.controller('productsCtrl', function($scope, categorySortedProducts){

    var admin = this;

    $scope.sortedProducts = categorySortedProducts;

    console.log($scope.sortedProducts);


    ...

})
```

(^^ The console.log works by the way!)

Then finally in my html view I simply have this:

```
<pre>{{sortedProducts | json}}</pre>
```

I do have the controller loaded in my route and it is loaded as admin. (productsCtrl as admin).

**UPDATE 2**

So it looks like the console.log() is kind of weird. This is what it looks like:

```
Array[0]
   category-one[12]
   categroy-two[15]
```

Is that normal, for the parent to show Array[0]? Just trying to find issues.

Answer (score 1):

I changed in my promise the following.

```
var temp = [];
```

to

```
var temp = {};
```

And now everything shows up in my View. I'm guessing it's because my data isn't setup sequentially like `[]` is typically used for.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is looking on the scope but your `admin` variable is locally-defined and not attached to Angular's scope.

Change your code:

```
$scope.admin.sortedProducts = temp;
```

So why did it work in a `console.log` and not in your view?  Because the view is looking on the controller's scope.  But your console.log was looking in the local namespace which doesn't need to be on Angular's scope.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but turns out the OP is using controllerAs syntax and `admin` is actually the local reference to `this`. Something else is obviously going on, but given the bit of code posted it's unlikely to be diagnosed.